# How check if field exists with firestore rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a firestore database with a collection of products and a collection of categories.

I want give at the user the delete permission on the categories collection only if the category document not have a `products` field.

the products field is an array of reference.

I have this rules:

```
match /shops/{shopId} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if false;
  match /categories/{category=**}{      
    allow read: if true;
    allow write: if resource.data.products == null;
  }
}
```

But this rules not works, I cannot write or update a document.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the client query code, as well as the data it's trying to modify in the database.  Rules are not meaningful on their own - they need to be paired with specific code and data.

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
match /shops/{shopId} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if false;
  match /categories/{category=**}{      
    allow read: if true;
    allow create: if true;
    allow update, delete: if !('products' in resource.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer, on create resource is null and this may have caused an error for you

Answer (score 10):

Using a helper Function as below

```
function hasProducts(){
  return resource.data.keys().hasAny(["products"])
}

match /shops/{shopId} {
  allow read: if true;
  allow write: if false;
  match /categories/{category=**}{      
    allow read: if true;
    allow write: if !hasProducts();
  }
}
```